# Best way in 2021 to configure babel for an npm browser library & TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, npm, babeljs, libraries

I'm developing [a library](https://trpc.io) that is built with [preconstruct](https://preconstruct.tools/) (& hence babel).

I want it to build nicely & not include unnecessary junk.

### Questions

What is the right way to configure babel & `@babel/preset-env` for a browser library?

I need the libraries to support IE11, so need to rewrite async/await, etc.

### My current setup

You can have a look at the PR here: https://github.com/trpc/trpc/pull/174

- `packages/client` & `packages/react` uses the below babel config
- `packages/server` uses a different babel config that uses node as a target

This works but I have no idea if it's the right approach. Each browser package has `dependency` of `@babel/runtime` - is this the best way?

#### `babel.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    "@babel/preset-react",
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: "> 0.25%, not dead",
      },
    ],
  ],
  plugins: [
    "@babel/transform-runtime",
    "babel-plugin-annotate-pure-calls",
    "babel-plugin-dev-expression",
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { loose: true }],
  ],
  babelrcRoots: [
    "packages/*"
  ]
};
```

Comment: Further question: should  addI `exclude: ['@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator'],`? Seems like a lot of lib authors do that - does the user's webpack config or whatever typically do async transform automatically?